# Eclipse doesn't recognize listFiles(Filter paramFileFilter)

Tags: java, eclipse

How can I fix this? Eclipse doesn't recognize this function:

```
listFiles(Filter paramFileFilter)
```

See these screenshots:

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Which `File` have you imported? Is it `java.io.File`?

Comment: And where does `ExtensionFilter` come from ? Does it implement a java.io.FileFilter ?

Comment: thanks, ExtensionFilter was implemented with javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter. I changed ExtentionFilter implementation for java.io.FileFilter and it worked. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the type of `FileFilter`; chances are that it's not `java.io.FileFilter`

Answer (score 0):

In such cases always check the import statements for the involved method and arguments. Chances are high you imported some x.y.FileFilter, but wanted a.b.FileFilter. You can most easily do the check by hovering over the identifiers and the method call, where you will see the fully qualified name.

This error happens mostly when using the wrong quick fix when creating those imports in Eclipse, so make sure to select the correct "Import XYZ" quick fix by looking at the package name in braces at the end of the tool tip.

Answer (score 0):

Many years later, but I just hit this same problem myself. My problem was that I created a file filter to use with JFileChooser, and then I tried to use the same filter with File.listFiles. The problem is that there are two different classes both called "FileFilter", or rather, a class and an interface.

JFileChooser uses javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter. File.listFiles uses java.io.FileFilter.

But fortunately, both require a function with signature public boolean accept(File f). So the solution is easy enough. I change my file filter from "extends javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter" to "extends javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter implements java.io.FileFilter". Then it works for both cases.